# Efficient way of sending thousands of API requests

Tags: api

I was wondering if there is an efficient way to make thousands of API requests every 10 seconds to so. It would be similar to a stock scanner so I would need to be able to get data from thousands of stocks and if a certain condition is met than I will get alerted. Another problem I am concerned with is if the stock symbols are stored in a file is there a way to loop through all the symbols at the same time instead of chronologically like you normally would in a for loop?